# Optimal Kafka Producer Options for Failover and Recovery

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

I would like to fine tune the `KafkaTemplate` options for the Producer, to handle as optimally as possible, the various failover and recovery scenarios.

We have our `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` running in `sync` mode (i.e. waiting for the send operation results - **see:** `acks` below). *Note:* this is necessary in the current version of Kafka to enable **ErrorChannel** reporting.

Here are the options I have choosen:

- `acks = 1` *(we are performing basic acknowlegement from the Kafka
  broker leader)*
- `retries = 10`
- `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1` *(This will keep the messages in order, if an error state is reached)*
- `linger.ms = 1` *(not sure about this one or whether it is relevant?)*
- `request.timeout.ms = 5000`
  *(five seconds for timeout, this will work with the retries - so
  total time of 50 seconds, before the message is deemed to have failed and will then appear on the error channel)*
- `enable.idempotence = false` *(again, not sure about this option?)*
- `retry.backoff.ms = 100` *(this is the default - again is it worth playing with?)*

How do these values sound?
Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I leave tags as you selected, but doesn't sound like the question is related to Spring Integration or Spring Kafka. Just indeed Apache Kafka Producer options. You would face the same problem even without Spring Integration and Spring Kafka.

Comment: [official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) gives good description of these configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old post about Kafka producer tuning: http://ingest.tips/2015/07/19/tips-for-improving-performance-of-kafka-producer/

TLDR version:

Pay attention on the 'batch.size' and 'linger.ms' parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the article is very informative! Do you have any further suggestions, with failover and recovery in mind?

Comment: @RobertSmith it's complicated topic. What I've tried is to log the failed messages in order to process them later. You can do it in the Kafka producer callback. IMHO this devends very on your workload. So I would suggest you try different settings and compare results.

In terms of recovery you should look on your cluster topology - such things like replication factor, how many partitions etc.

If you want your producer send messages faster you can try different 'ack' values.

Comment: That is the approach we are using - we plan to do the exact same thing with failed messages via the error channel. For `ack` values, we are going with the default which is one (apparently this is required, with the current version of Kafka so that failed messages will end up in the error channel).